# Perl regular expression for phone numbers

Tags: regex, perl

I want to normalize a phone with a regex in perl. Phone numbers are allowed in national and international format, the destination format should be international starting with "+":

National format:

```
022112345678 -> Destination Format: +4922112345678
```

International Format:

```
004922112345678 -> Destination Format: +4922112345678 
+4922112345678 -> Destination Format: +4922112345678
+43123456789 -> Destination Format: +4943123456789
0043123456789 -> Destination Format: +4943123456789
...
```

Invalid formats:

```
+022112345678
00022112345670
00221abc
...
```

Can this be done with one regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

You can search for this regex:

```
/^(?:(?:\+|00)49|0)([1-9]\d+)$/gm
```

And replace by:

```
+49$1
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fW1gU9/1)

Comment: Actually this does not allow numbers from other countries than Germany like +43123456789 or 0043123456789

Comment: Correct because your question/examples didn't have that requirement earlier. Besides how can a code add 2 digit country code of multiple countries e.g. `022112345678 -> Destination Format: +4922112345678` ?

Comment: if number starts with one zero, we assume number is in national format, so to make it international we need no replace 0 with +49. If number start with 00 or + we assume number is already in international format. In this simple check we only want to make sure that the number does not contain

Comment: Did your comment got cut off? Better you clarify this in question but probably this will need more than one regex.